# Play Framework - after deployment with dist command I get "No query defined for that name [...]" error

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework

I have a working Java Play Framework application in debug mode which uses Hibernate JPA for persistence.

I have a problem when I'm trying to deploy and run application in production environment. I have built the application by using dist task and have it deployed to a production environment.

When I run any service in my application that is connecting the database and is using @NamedQueries @NamedQuery annotations to create query I get the following error in log:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No query defined for that name [myq]]
```

The same service is working well in debug environment.

Here is the code from the class that contains the annotations:

```
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
...

@Entity
@Table(name = "user", catalog = "mydb")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = User.BY_USERNAME, query = 
            "select u from User u where u.username=:username")
})
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    public static final String BY_USERNAME = "myq";
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the imports. Instead of:

```
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
```

use the following:

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQueries;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQuery;
```